# Setting constant value for an agent created in a source block

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent that has a variable that I need to set as a constant

[image]

When adding this population to main all agents get generated without any issue.

But when adding a source block to create this agent and use it in a flow chart...

[image]

I get this error

[image]

It appears that the agents get created without access to the utils class...

How to have a constant variable that uses randomness in an agent created in a process flow block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick workaround: Just use a parameter instead. In its "on change" code, you can `error()` the model so it is never accidentally changed.

Now you have the same setup: a constant random value, unique for each agent instance but never changeable...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. When I read the answer I was assuming that I would need to set up the parameter from the source in the "New agent:" field with a value for the parameter, but simple changing it to a parameter worked nicely and it still has the default value of uniform(100). And now it is public and "protected" save as a constant variable.